# Como capturar parâmetros por XSL?

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, querystring

Estou modificando um formulário no Sharepoint e quero pegar os parms que estão sendo passados na url, alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
 <xsl:element name='a'>
 <xsl:attribute name='href'>
 http://smallserver:777/tools/geraDoc2.aspx?
 <xsl:value-of select="parametroComNomeDeIDqueEstáNaURL" />
 </xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Sharepoint você pode utlizar `ParameterBinding` para associar uma chave da *QueryString* à um parâmetro. Assim, para uma QueryString `?IDSelecionado=10`, o seguinte código:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="IDSelecionado" Location="QueryString(IDSelecionado)"/>
Código correspondent no XSL: 
<xsl:param name=“IDSelecionado”/>
```

Irá retornar `10` quando o parâmetro `IDSelecionado` for avaliado.

Fonte: [MSDN, 'XSLT Parameter Bindings'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806155.aspx)

Comment: Mas Location="QueryString(IDSelecionado) <-- é nome do meu parametro??

Comment: @RogersCorrêa ParameterBinding vai obter o valor da sua Querystring e então transformá-lo em um Parâmetro que você pode então consumir.

Comment: Por exemplo meu parm é ID, então é o que vai dentro da QueryString?

Comment: Blza entendi! agora só tenho um problema, como coloco esse valor em tela? uso o xsl:value:of?